# What do I do with the X11 symlink in Relocated Items?

Tags: macos-catalina

After updating to Catalina, my Mac has a folder `/Users/Shared/Relocated Items/Security/usr`.

Inside is an X11 folder, but it's a symlink:

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  8  8 Oct  2017 X11 -> /opt/X11`

I'd like to remove this whole Relocated Items thing, but it's not allowing me to remove the X11 thing.

`almo@SilentMac usr % unlink X11
unlink: X11: Operation not permitted
almo@SilentMac usr % rm X11
rm: X11: Operation not permitted
almo@SilentMac usr % sudo rm X11
Password:
rm: X11: Operation not permitted`

Do I need to leave this here? Or is there some way to remove it?

Comment: duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371980/catalina-upgrade-cannot-delete-relocated-items